# Как поднять ipv6 на туннеле pptp?

Tags: debian, centos, ipv6

Есть pptp-client и ipv4, присоединенный через pptp. Локальный адрес имеет вид 192.168.1.2 Можно ли сделать ipv6 из этого адреса?

К примеру:
у меня есть статический ipv4 и я хочу сделать ipv6. В /etc/network/interfaces прописываю:

```
auto tun6to4
iface tun6to4 inet6 v4tunnel
    pre-up modprobe ipv6
    address 2002:4e9b:2аа1:0::1 
        netmask 64              
    gateway ::192.88.99.1
    endpoint any
    local 78.101.123.209

iface tun6to4 inet6 static
address 2002:4e9b:2аа1:0:e22d:40a4:23da:1111
  netmask 64
iface tun6to4 inet6 static
address 2002:4e9b:2аа1:0:e22d:40a4:23da:2222
  netmask 64
gateway 2002:4e9b:2аа1:0::1
```

таким образом я из статического ipv4 поднял сеть ipv6 и могу писать сколько угодно ipv6.

Интересует, можно ли поднять такое дело не на статическом айпи сервера, а на ip, подключенном через pptp (vpn-туннель)?

Comment: 6to4-туннель (также как и pptp- и все прочие туннели) не «поднимается на ip», а устнавливается **между двумя компьютерами**. // ipv6-трафик можно «раздать» с сервера через pptp-туннель: http://computer-outlines.over-blog.com/0012/12/vpn-4-debian-pptp-server-w-ipv4-and-ipv6.html

Comment: а можно с сервера раздать "сеть" или что-то в этом роде, а на клиенте, я указываю адресов 100 и выбираю через какой пользоваться. Потом Сервер это обрабатывает и пускает "в интернет" по выбранному мной белому ipv6.

Comment: попробуйте. ссылку на инструкцию я привёл.

Comment: спасибо, это то, что я искал. Немного нужно разобраться, но уже есть результат.
Сделайте ваш комментарий  лучшим ответом и поставьте лайк от меня. А то лайкать комментарии нельзя =)

Comment: soulsoul, ответ в [виде ссылки — это «плохой» ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). для полноценного же ответа требуются либо глубокие теоретические знания, либо чисто практические. у меня нет, к сожалению, ни того, ни другого. но вы можете сами [ответить на свой вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), изложив свой практический опыт.